# List of String Values and differentiate int and string values

Tags: c#

List of String Values and differentiate int and string values

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "1", "2", "three", "4", "five", "eight", "9" };

List<int> output1 = new List<int>{};  // keep the list here integer values
List<string> output2 = new List<string> { }; // keep the list here non numericic values
```

Please help me out...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `List<int> output1 = input.Select(int.Parse).ToList()`?

Comment: @SonerGönül it require filter for non numerice value otherwise it will throw exception

Answer (score 4):

```
 foreach(string item in input)
 {
     int result = 0;

     if(Int32.TryParse(item, out result))
     {
        output1.Add(result);
     }
     else
     {
        output2.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You are parsing the value once (not using `TryParse` then `Parse`), and your code is clear. My only suggestion is to move `result ` into the scope of the `foreach ` as it's not needed outside. +1

Answer (score 0):

by looping your list `bool k=int.TryParse(numberString , out temp );`and passing your value as parameter you can find weather it is a integer or not

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "1", "2", "three", "4", "five", "eight", "9" };


List<int> output1 = new List<int>{};  // keep the list here integer values
List<string> output2 = new List<string> { }; // keep the list here non numericic values

foreach(var temp in input)
{
   bool k=int.TryParse(numberString , out temp );
   if(k==true)
   {
     output1.add(temp)
   }
   else
   {
     output2.add(temp)
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't build.  `temp` is of type `string`, but you try to add it to `output1`, which is `List<int>`. You should introduce another variable to hold the value of `TryParse`, since you've used it to iterate over (as a string) **and** to contain the parsed value (as an int).

Comment: If i show output it's getting the like this                                                                                          System.Collection.Generics.List '1[System.Int32]                                           System.Collection.Generics.List '1[System.Int32]                                           System.Collection.Generics.List '1[System.String]                                           System.Collection.Generics.List '1[System.Int32]                                                   System.Collection.Generics.List '1[System.String] .............

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
int outInt;
var intStringValues = input.Where(o => int.TryParse(o, out outInt)).ToList();

List<int> output1 = intStringValues.Select(int.Parse).ToList();     
List<string> output2 = input.Except(intStringValues).ToList();
```

Here's a demostrating fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVqloX

More likely not as performant as a simple `foreach`, but just for the sake of doing it linq-style